# When to use ":" on property passed to component in Vue?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-props

I've seen an example block of code in an component that passes two props down. One uses a ":" while the other doesn't. But I can't figure out why one needs and one doesn't. What does it stand for and how does it affect the info passed down?

```
<date-picker
      format="D MMM YYYY"
      :options="{ firstDay: 1 }">
</date-picker>
```

and inside the component

```
    props: {
        format: { default: 'YYYY-MM-DD' },
        options: { default: {} }
    }
```

Comment: Whar value you get for `format` in component? `

Comment: It's simple: With element properties: if you are passing plain text, don't use colon. If you are passing any other value, use it. With objects: learn JavaScript first, then learn JS framework. And not vice versa.

Comment: @VladislavLadicky I'm really sorry but could you point me to any reference for passing in element properties, I believe you are right with passing plain text vs objects, but I've never read this being mentioned anywhere. And would it conflict or be affected with v-bind as ":" is a shorthand for it?

Answer (score 2):

`:` in the template is shorthand for v-bind mean for data binding which mean in your case `:option` is to tell that the string on the right side is javascript variable. while the latter is just a normal javascript object there no need to binding.
here some link of reference: https://v1.vuejs.org/guide/syntax.html

Comment: But the problem is that :option is not binded to anything. Yet when I remove the ':', it breaks. Vice versa for the 'format', if I try to 'bind' it using a ':' it breaks.

Comment: the binding meaning might be a bit miss leading but it actually just means the string on the right side evaluate it in javascript. since normal HTML can only be passed with string without the `:`